# Best way to manage hierarhical data in MySQL to keep track of tiers

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, hierarchical-data

I'm working on a project that deals with hierarchical data of tiers in relation to hiring. Here's the scenario:

- A hires B. B is now Tier 1 of A
- B hires C. C is now Tier 2 of A, and Tier 1 of B
- C hires D. D is now Tier 3 of A, Tier 2 of B, and Tier 1 of C
- D hires E. E is now Tier 4 of A, Tier 3 of B, Tier 2 of C, and Tier 1 of D.
- B hired F. F is now Tier 2 of A, and Tier 1 of B
- Deleting someone in the tiers does not move anyone up meaning tier structure remains the same upon deletion

I will be using their tier rank to assign specific percentages to where they can be all designated and totaled. What is the best way to go about this in MySQL 8+ especially with the introduction of CTE? I was considering Lineage Column/Path Enumeration because I've done something kind of similar in the past in SQL Server with hierarchyid, but I would like to hear your thoughts on best practices/approach for this in MySQL8+ because I'd also like an option that as referential integrity if possible.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  8.0 has Recursive CTEs for dealing with hierarchical data.

Comment: I don't wanna be that guy... but I said "..MySQL 8+ especially with the introduction of CTE?" and mentioned MySQL8+ again in my last statement lol. Was your idea of implementation for recursive CTE the same as The Impaler listed below?

Answer (score 1):

A simple hierarchical structure will work. If you want to keep the original tiers after deleting an employee, then you'll need to *soft-delete* the rows instead of deleting them from the table.

For example, you can do:

```
create table employee (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(10) not null,
  active int1 default 1 check (active in (0, 1)),
  hired_by int references employee (id)
);

insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (1, 'A', null);
insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (2, 'B', 1);
insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (3, 'C', 2);
insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (4, 'D', 3);
insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (5, 'E', 4);
insert into employee (id, name, hired_by) values (6, 'F', 2);

update employee set active = 0 where id = 4; -- "Soft-delete" of D
```

Then, you can get all related employees starting from a specific one. For example, if you want to start from `ID = 1`, you can do:

```
with recursive
e as (
  select *, 0 as tier from employee where id = 1
 union all
  select r.*,
    e.tier + 1
  from e
  join employee r on r.hired_by = e.id
)
select * from e;
```

Result:

```
 id  name  active  hired_by  tier 
 --- ----- ------- --------- ---- 
 1   A     1       null      0    
 2   B     1       1         1    
 3   C     1       2         2    
 6   F     1       2         2    
 4   D     0       3         3    
 5   E     1       4         4
```

You can modify the query above to run in reverse (starting from the hired employee and going up the hierarchy) or to go sideways if you want. It's easy to walk graphs with recursive CTEs, not just hierarchies.

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ezxy3txiwxhH6LWBRyCMf1/0).

Comment: Thanks for this! To make sure my peanut brain understands this right, your "select *, 0 as tier from employee where id = 1" I could specify any id I want and it will always set the tier to 0 and just add 1 for each hire from that point? Meaning if I make the id = 3 in your example, C would be tier 0 and then D would be tier 1?

Comment: @MarlonBrando Yes, change the `WHERE` predicate to define the starting point you want.